# How do I make vim treat $ as an identifier character?

Tags: vim

I'd like to have vim (after pressing Ctrl+]) look up tags containing special characters like `$` or `@`. I can do it with the `:tag` command (e.g., `tag $some$symbol`) but it doesn't work with `Ctrl+]`.
How can I configure what vim treats as an identifier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at [`:help CTRL-]`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/tagsrch.txt.html#CTRL-%5D), it says:

> ```
> CTRL-]              Jump to the definition of the keyword under the
>                     cursor.  Same as ":tag {name}", where {name} is the
>                     keyword under or after cursor.
> ```

From there, one might find [`:help 'iskeyword'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27iskeyword%27), or end up with [`:help word`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#word), which explains:

> A word consists of a sequence of letters, digits and underscores, or a
>   sequence of other non-blank characters, separated with white space (spaces,
>   tabs, ).  This can be changed with the 'iskeyword' option.  An empty line
>   is also considered to be a word.

Therefore, you need to add `$` to the `'iskeyword'` option:

```
:setlocal iskeyword+=$
```

#### Making that permanent

The `'iskeyword'` option is *local to buffer*, and many syntax scripts rely on correct settings for highlighting. Therefore, it's not recommended to change this globally for all filetypes (with `:set`, in your `~/.vimrc`).

Instead, you should identify the (few) filetype(s) were you need this, and then define this only locally.

Put the corresponding `:setlocal` command into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim`, where `{filetype}` is the actual filetype (e.g. `java`). (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`; use of the *after* directory allows you to override any default filetype settings done by `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim`.)

Alternatively, you could define an `:autocmd FileType {filetype} setlocal iskeyword+=$` directly in your `~/.vimrc`, but this tends to become unwieldy once you have many customizations.

Comment: Thansk a  lot. I'd done help `ctrl-]` but didn't make it to `iskeyword` from there. Very nice answer.